# IndexedDB copy from VM to Local Machine

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, indexeddb

I have an IndexedDB that was created with Chrome on a VM. I copied the folder to my local machine, and now I would like to see it in devtools. (and I have a script that will create CSVs for me)

My problem is that all the files are deleted as soon as I navigate to the domain and open devtools. It then adds empty LOG and LOCK files.

**What I've Tried:**

**Using the IndexedDB created on my local machine:**

- Remove and re-add IndexedDB into the same chrome profile on the same machine: **works fine.**
- Copy IndexedDB to a different chrome profile on
  the same machine: **works fine.**
- Changing the domain in the DB folder
  name: Files not deleted, but DB won't show up in devtools

**Using the IndexedDB from the VM:**

- Copying the IndexedDB domain folder (https_domain...): The files are deleted 
  and the log file shows: 2020/04/20-15:31:04.420 1cc4 Delete type=2 **#897** There is one line for each of the LDB files I copied in.
- Copying only the LDB files and manifest file - same issue as above

Cross Posted to:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1543794/indexeddb-copy-from-vm-to-local-machine
- [IndexedDB copy from VM to Local Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323850/indexeddb-copy-from-vm-to-local-machine)
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/141564/indexeddb-copy-from-vm-to-local-machine

Edit: This has randomly started working, using the same files that I was trying it with before :S

Comment: See if there's a clue in the [debug log](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging). Note that the entire folder should be copied, not just the ldb.

Comment: I've also tried copying the entire folder, I'll have a look in the debug log, thanks